# How to set password on already existing winrar archive and encrypt it also?

Tags: passwords, encryption, compression, archiving, winrar

Not when creating new archive, but on **existing archive**. I would also like to know how to do that in other archiver.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can do it by using this method . 
Tools > Convert Archives > Compression > General > Set Password > then click ok and save . :)

Comment: Nice! Talk about a BURIED feature!

Comment: Hahahahahahahaha.... what the ... :D

Comment: I don't know if this was different in earlier versions, but I found the 'set password' button under 'general' not the 'advanced' tab. Still, you got me more than half the way there!

Comment: Works great. Note that WinRAR 3.42 has another password option under File->Password (I don't know what this does).

Comment: This also works with .zip archives in WinRar :)  Also remember to check 'delete original archives' so that you can replace the original with encrypted version.  Otherwise, you must manually delete the unencrypted version.

Comment: And thats why nobody buys WinRar, why do they hide the options so hard?

Comment: Slight clarification (or possibly a slightly different method; not sure): Double-click on the RAR file (in e.g., Windows Explorer). That opens a WinRAR session. In that session, select the RAR file > top menu > Tools > Convert archives > Compression button > General tab > Set password > enter new password > OK > OK > Yes (I'm sure I want to encrypt converted archives) > OK > enter old password > OK > Close.

Comment: thank you so much!.. this works like a charm! =)

Comment: It does indeed work. Is there a way to do this from winrar command line ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as the password is generally used as the hash/similar for the file, so, anything that changes it will require an intensive operation to change all files.

The fastest and easiest thing by far is to extract all files and create a new archive with the security set.

Not saying it isn't possible to do what you want, but I haven't seen the option to do it.

Comment: I added file to archive and set password which casused everything to update. Now archive is password protected, but has unnecessary file. I removed it and archive **remained protected**.

Comment: @Boris - Technically what you did was exactly what you DID NOT want to do.  You actually did create a new archive it was just invisible to you.

Comment: Then where is the old archive? In temp directory?

Comment: This is the correct answer. The picked answer actually recompresses the archive, so it's not what OP wants. Neither what I want... been looking to set a password to a 60GB archive that took 12 hours to make without recompressing it... and it's not possible. Since I have no choice, it'll end up as a rar in a rar situation.

Comment: @JasonXA It looks to me like the OP wants to *change* the password and end up with an archive the same as the existing archive; i.e. same filename, same contents, same sequence of files, etc. Is that not what happens with the accepted answer ? Other than processing time, is the archive altered in some fundamental way ? I'm wondering if I'm missing something. Thanks

Comment: @JeffBrower, practically, but technically, on point to the question the answer is that it's not possible. Setting up a password would imply taking the already archived binary contents and encrypting it. That function doesn't exist. Converting it means decompression > recompression > encryption to a new file, which is the same as creating a new archive also which is stated in the OPs question as a not. In my comment I also have a reason why, as it would not be different in either time nor processing power, this it's not a way, it's a compromise in getting the required output.

Comment: @JasonXA, ok got it. Thanks for the careful explanation

Answer (score -3):

There is a better way of doing it. go to Options>Settings>Compression>Create Default>Set Password>Then click Ok and you're done! (At least it's easier to navigate.)

Comment: That is not the answer to the question; this just sets how archives are made 'from now on.'